# How should I name my RGB channels, using cv::Mat_

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to access my matrix elements in the following manner:

```
frame[i][j].Red
```

, that is, the (i,j)-th pixe's red channel.

I have tried:

```
typedef struct{unsigned char Blue,Green,Red;}Pixel;  
typedef cv::Mat_<Pixel> Image;
```

However when trying to imread(), imwrite() or whatever with the thus defined type, g++ greets me with:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in convertTo, file /home/users/mvitkov/projects/opencv-legacy/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 937
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
    what():  /home/users/mvitkov/projects/opencv-legacy/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:937: error: (-215) func != 0 in function convertTo
```

---

Update: So no answer to my probably badly asked question. Too bad. The essence of the question is how to address the individual channels with sensible names (red, green, bkue), and not the c-era array indexing notation `[2]`. Duh!

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html).

Comment: why do you use imread() and imwrite()?
Those functions are in matlab, but not openCV.
Also, what do you want to accomplish by defining Pixel?

Comment: "How to use ``Mat_`` for multi-channel images/matrices? This is simple - just pass Vec as Mat_ parameter" Not helping. I cannot name the vector elements.

Comment: It's going to take more than hunting for single sentences.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit, Yea, nearly an year and no one has answered how to typedef the channel components. It really takes a lot more ;p

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you access each channel:

```
blue = frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]; 
green = frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]; 
red = frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
```

The above code assumes that you have a 3-channel image where each value is an *8-bit unsigned char (`CV_8UC3`)*. This type is used in many common image formats. However, if you have a different type of 3-channel image, here's what you do:

- If the image type is 3-channel float (`CV_32FC3`), then replace `cv::Vec3b` with `cv::Vec3f`
- If the image type is 3-channel double (`CV_64FC3`), then replace `cv::Vec3b` with `cv::Vec3d`
- If the image type is 3-channel int (`CV_32SC3`), then replace `cv::Vec3b` with `cv::Vec3i`
- If the image type is 3-channel short int (`CV_16SC3`) or 16-bit uchar (`CV_16UC3`), then replace `cv::Vec3b` with `cv::Vec3s`

Not sure what image format you're using? Try calling `getImgType(frame)` (see the code below).

```
string getImgType(cv::Mat frame)
{
    int imgTypeInt = frame.type();
    int numImgTypes = 28; // 7 base types, with 4 channel options each (C1, ..., C4)
    int enum_ints[] = {CV_8UC1,  CV_8UC2,  CV_8UC3,  CV_8UC4, CV_8SC1,  CV_8SC2,  CV_8SC3,  CV_8SC4, CV_16UC1, CV_16UC2, CV_16UC3, CV_16UC4, CV_16SC1, CV_16SC2, CV_16SC3, CV_16SC4, CV_32SC1, CV_32SC2, CV_32SC3, CV_32SC4, CV_32FC1, CV_32FC2, CV_32FC3, CV_32FC4, CV_64FC1, CV_64FC2, CV_64FC3, CV_64FC4};
    string enum_strings[] = {"CV_8U",  "CV_8UC1",  "CV_8UC2",  "CV_8UC3",  "CV_8UC4", "CV_8SC1",  "CV_8SC2",  "CV_8SC3",  "CV_8SC4", "CV_16UC1",  "CV_16UC2",  "CV_16UC3",  "CV_16UC4", "CV_16SC1", "CV_16SC2", "CV_16SC3", "CV_16SC4", "CV_32SC1", "CV_32SC2", "CV_32SC3", "CV_32SC4", "CV_32FC1", "CV_32FC2", "CV_32FC3", "CV_32FC4", "CV_64FC1", "CV_64FC2", "CV_64FC3", "CV_64FC4"};
    for(int i=0; i<numImgTypes; i++)
    {
        if(imgTypeInt == enum_ints[i]) return enum_strings[i];
    }
    return "unknown image type";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the image type is 3-channel short int (CV_16SC3) or 16-bit uchar (CV_16UC3), then replace cv::Vec3b with cv::Vec3s

this is simply not correct. I adressed a 3 channel 16 bit unsigned image once with < Vec3s>, and got a negative value G:29096 B:-21671 R:23413 returned.

If CV_16UC3, adress Mat with < Vec3w>. Using this I got G:29096 B:43865 R:23413

the "s" in CV_16SC3 stands for signed and not short.