# OpenCV: negative BGR values despite CV_16UC3

Tags: c++, opencv

I simply can't understand the opencv Mat types:

CV_16UC3 is well known as unsigned 16 bit 3 channel integer. However when I access each channels, I get negative values. According to [How should I name my RGB channels, using cv::Mat_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272120/how-should-i-name-my-rgb-channels-using-cvmat) Vec3s is the keyword to access. Here is what I did:

```
Mat mat_l(img_height,img_width,CV_16UC3);
mat_l = imread("/home/zhao/workspace/rectified_images/l_rectified_fountain.ppm");
cout << vec_mats_l[1].at<Vec3s>(44,500)[0] << " " 
     << vec_mats_l[1].at<Vec3s>(44,500)[1] << " " 
     << vec_mats_l[1].at<Vec3s>(44,500)[2] << endl;
```

Output is : 27522 -32382 -32407

why negative values despite type beeing defined unsigned???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try imread(path, -1);

without the flag, the image will be *forced* into CV_8UC3

(you can check the outcome with `cout << mat_l.type();`)

also, preallocating mat_l has no effect at all when you use imread, it will be overwritten anyway, so better leave it empty.

---

"why negative values" - Vec3s is signed. the unsigned version is Vec3w

Comment: thx, this solved my problem. a list of possible return values from Mat.type() and what they mean: http://ninghang.blogspot.de/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html. Also in case image only has 8 bit color and you want to print the value out, do cout << (uint)mat.at<vec3b>.(row,col)[channel];